# Jest not able to check promise rejection

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to check the promise rejection for the DatadogService.sendMetric()

DatadogService.ts

```
 import { client, v2 } from "@datadog/datadog-api-client";
 import { getRootLogger } from "@backstage/backend-common";
 import { Logger } from 'winston';

 export class DatadogService {
    private readonly logger: Logger;
    apiInstance: v2.MetricsApi;
    
    constructor(apiKey : string | undefined) {
      const configurationOpts = {
            authMethods: {
              apiKeyAuth: apiKey
            },
      };  
      const configuration = client.createConfiguration(configurationOpts);
      this.apiInstance = new v2.MetricsApi(configuration);
      this.logger = getRootLogger();
    }
  
    async sendMetric(metricName: string, tags: string[]) : Promise<any> {
      const params: v2.MetricsApiSubmitMetricsRequest = {
            body: {
              series: [
                {
                  metric: metricName,
                  type: 1,
                  points: [
                    {
                      timestamp: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
                      value: 1,
                    },
                  ],
                  tags: tags,
                },
              ],
            },
        };
        try {
            await this.apiInstance.submitMetrics(params);
            this.logger.info(`Metric ${metricName} submitted data ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
            return Promise.resolve('metric sent');
        } catch(error) {
            this.logger.error(`Metric submission failed for ${metricName} with data ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
            return Promise.reject('Error occurred while submitting metric : ' + metricName);
        }
    };
 }
```

DatadogService.test.ts

```
import { DatadogService } from './DatadogService';
import { constructTagsArray } from './utils';

describe('DatadogService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('send metrics to throw error due to invalid key ', async () => {
    const DATADOG_API_KEY = 'DUMMY_API_KEY';
    const tags = {
      tagA: 'tagAValue',
      tagB: 'tagBValue'
    };
    const response = await new DatadogService(DATADOG_API_KEY).sendMetric('datadogMetricName', constructTagsArray(tags));
    const rejectMessage = 'Error occurred while submitting metric : datadogMetricName'
    await expect(response).rejects.toThrow(rejectMessage);
  });
  
});
```

I'm getting below error

```
DatadogService › send metrics to throw error due to invalid key 

    thrown: "Error occurred while submitting metric : datadogMetricName"

       8 |   });
       9 |
    > 10 |   it('send metrics to throw error due to invalid key ', async () => {
         |   ^
      11 |     const DATADOG_API_KEY = 'DUMMY_API_KEY';
      12 |     const tags = {
      13 |       tagA: 'tagAValue ',

      at service/DatadogService.test.ts:10:3
      at Object.<anonymous> (service/DatadogService.test.ts:5:1)
```

Can you help me how should I check for the rejected promise.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test the promise rejection by using **try catch**

**From the Jest docs** : Errors can be handled using the .catch method. Make sure to add expect.assertions to verify that a certain number of assertions are called. Otherwise a fulfilled promise would not fail the test.

https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-async#error-handling

```
import { DatadogService } from './DatadogService';
import { constructTagsArray } from './utils';

describe('DatadogService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  
  it('send metrics to throw error due to invalid key ', async () => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const DATADOG_API_KEY = 'DUMMY_API_KEY ';
      const tags = {
        tagA: 'tagAValue',
        tagB: 'tagBValue'
      };
      const rejectMessage = 'Error occurred while submitting metric : datadogMetricName'
      try {
        await new DatadogService(DATADOG_API_KEY).sendMetric('datadogMetricName', constructTagsArray(tags));
      } catch(e) {
        expect(e).toEqual(rejectMessage);
      }
  });
  
});
```